# Simple search feature, MySQL prepared statement issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently in the process of creating a very simple search feature for a website in which the user is able to search a database for events using a number of different criteria (from one to many, varied number) and I'm experiencing an issue with the prepared statement I'm using, the bind_param() in particularly.

Here is the relevant PHP code:

```
...
...
$title = (empty($_POST['eventTitle'])) ? null : $_POST['eventTitle'];
$venue = (empty($_POST['venue'])) ? null : $_POST['venue'];
$catID = (empty($_POST['catID'])) ? null : $_POST['catID'];
$start = (empty($_POST['start'])) ? null : $_POST['start'];
$end = (empty($_POST['end'])) ? null : $_POST['end'];
$price = (empty($_POST['price'])) ? null : $_POST['price'];

include 'database_conn.php';

$sql = 'SELECT eventID, eventTitle, venueID, catID, eventStartDate, 
eventEndDate, eventPrice FROM te_events WHERE 1';

$sqlCondition = '';

$bindFirstArg = '"';
$bindSecondArg = '';

if($title !== null && !empty($title)) {

    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . " AND eventTitle LIKE \"%" 
    . $title . "%\"";

}

if($venue !== null && $venue !== '0') {

    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . " AND venueID=?";
    $bindFirstArg = $bindFirstArg . "s";
    $bindSecondArg = $bindSecondArg . ", " . $venue;

}

if($catID !== null && $catID !== '0') {

    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . " AND catID=?";
    $bindFirstArg = $bindFirstArg . "s";
    $bindSecondArg = $bindSecondArg . ", " . $catID;

}

if($start !== null && $start !== '0') {

    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . " AND eventStartDate=?";
    $bindFirstArg = $bindFirstArg . "s";
    $bindSecondArg = $bindSecondArg . ", " . $start;

}

if($end !== null && $end !== '0') {

    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . " AND eventEndDate=?";
    $bindFirstArg = $bindFirstArg . "s";
    $bindSecondArg = $bindSecondArg . ", " . $end;

}

if($price !== null && !empty($price)) {

    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . " AND eventPrice=?";
    $bindFirstArg = $bindFirstArg . "i";
    $bindSecondArg = $bindSecondArg . ", " . $price;

}

$sql = $sql . $sqlCondition;
$bindFirstArg = $bindFirstArg . '"';

$search_stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);

if (false===$search_stmt) {

    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));

}


$search_stmt -> bind_param($bindFirstArg, $bindSecondArg);
$search_stmt -> execute();
$search_stmt -> bind_result($eventIDRes, $eventTitleRes, $venueIDRes, 
$catIDRes, $eventStartRes, $eventEndRes, $eventPriceRes);

while ($search_stmt->fetch()) {

    printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %i\n", $eventIDRes, $eventTitleRes, 
    $venueIDRes, $catIDRes, $eventStartRes, $eventEndRes, $eventPriceRes);

}

mysqli_stmt_close($search_stmt);
```

The error I'm receiving states

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w12019212/public_html/webdev/searchresult.php on line 101"

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to pass `bind_param` a parameter for *each* `?` you have in your query.  You are only passing it one parameter (`$bindSecondArg`).

Comment: MySQLi prepared statements require you to specify a data type for each parameter.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - $bindSecondArg is a variable used to hold the names of the variables that are within it depending on the users selection, so in reality it has multiple variables within it.

Comment: @Charlieabee: To you it has multiple variables, but `bind_param` just sees it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `bind_param` a *separate* argument for *each* `?` in your query, as well as the formats as the first parameter.  You can't pass it a comma-separated string, that won't work.  It just reads that as the first `?` and then complains that you didn't send it the rest.

Also, don't add quotes inside your `$bindFirstArg` string.  `bind_param` just wants a list of all the data types (`i`, `d`, `s`, or `b`) , it doesn't want `"` characters.

What you need to do is push your values into an array, then call `bind_param` via `call_user_func_array`.

```
$sqlCondition = '';

$bindFirstArg = '';
$bindParams = array();


// You need to bind $title as well, otherwise you are wide open to SQL
// injection and have just thrown out the benefits of prepared statements
if($title !== null && !empty($title)) {
    $sqlCondition .= " AND eventTitle LIKE ?";
    $bindFirstArg .= "s";

    // Add the `%` to the value, not the query
    $title = "%{$title}%";
   // bind_param wants these to be references
    $bindParams[] =& $title;

}

// Change all your ifs to look like this.
// They need to push into the $bindParams array
if($catID !== null && $catID !== '0') {
    $sqlCondition .= " AND catID=?";    
    $bindFirstArg .= "s";

    // bind_param wants these to be references
    $bindParams[] =& $catID;
}

// etc...

$sql .= $sqlCondition;
$search_stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// Call bind_param with the correct number of parameters
array_unshift($bindParams, $bindFirstArg);
// This will make sure the parameters are passed correctly.
// Each variable needs to be passed as a separate parameter
call_user_func_array(array($search_stmt, 'bind_param'), $bindParams);

$search_stmt->execute();
$search_stmt->bind_result($eventIDRes, $eventTitleRes, $venueIDRes, 
    $catIDRes, $eventStartRes, $eventEndRes, $eventPriceRes);

while ($search_stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %i\n", $eventIDRes, $eventTitleRes, 
        $venueIDRes, $catIDRes, $eventStartRes, $eventEndRes, $eventPriceRes);
}

$search_stmt->close();
```

Comment: Yes this works, thank you. However I'm not sure why it works so I'll have to go away and research that by myself!